# Why does ubuntu only show 200MiB of Ram

Tags: 14.04, unity, server

Under systems settings >> details >> overview it only shows 236.8 MiB of ram installed. Everything else looks correct but with this information my system is running extremely slow. It has 6GB ram in the computer. BTW it's an old PowerEdge 2800 server with Ubuntu Server 14 on it with ubuntu gui enabled

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         236M         226M      9.8M      92M       276k        32M
-/+ buffers/cache:        194M       42M
Swap:        4g            468M      3.5g
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Had this problem before, make sure OS Install Mode is disabled in BIOS settings.